# Extending interfaces changing method signature

Tags: java, php, oop, inheritance, interface

Consider the following interfaces

```
interface Foo1
{
    public function foo(BaseClass)
}
```

and

```
interface Foo2
{
    public function foo(SpecialClass)
}
```

where `SpecialClass` inherits from `BaseClass`.

Now, a `Foo1` instance could be used whenever a `Foo2` instance is required. I mean, if I need an object with a `foo` method that accepts a `SpecialClass`, I could do the job with an object with a `foo` method that accepts a `BaseClass`.

Hence I would like to be able to declare `Foo1` as a sublclass of `Foo2` (i.e. `Foo1 extends Foo2`).

In `PHP` (the language I usually work with) this is not possible and would produce a fatal error.

As far as I know this is feasible in Java, but would require to implement a specific `foo` method taking a special class as argument (am I wrong on this?).

Does all this make sense or am I missing something? Is there any other object oriented language that provides this out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

In java syntax the interface should be declared as following:

```
interface Foo2
{
    public void foo(SpecialClass b);
}

interface Foo1 extends Foo2
{
    public void foo(BaseClass s); // In Java doesn't inherits from Foo2.foo!
}
```

The above script is theoretically correct from inheritance perspective. Unfortunately, Java don't interprets it in the expected way: `Foo1.foo` and `Foo2.foo` are considered two different overloaded functions.

The only declaration accepted and interpreted by Java in the expected way is the following:

```
interface Foo2
{
    public void foo(BaseClass b);
}

interface Foo1 extends Foo2
{
    public void foo(BaseClass b);
}
```

And then you can write in your own implementation something like:

```
class Foo1Class implements Foo1
{
    public void foo(BaseClass b)
    {
        if(!(b instanceof SpecialClass)) throw new ClassCastException();

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood. My apologies. Above the mistake, the answer on Java language remains the same. I corrected the answer